# SQL Order by a specific value of a one to many field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

**The context :**

I have these three simple SQL tables : [my database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH5Vq.jpg)

- a *Request* has one or N *Request_Field*
- *Request_Field* is a pivot table

  - *Value* inside the pivot table *Request_Field* can sometimes contain dates in string format
- a Field has 0 or N *Request_Field*

These tables are part of a greater database and I cannot change them at the moment.

**My question :**

Is it possible to query multiple *"Request"* and order them by a specific value in *"Request_Field"* ?

**Example :**

| Request table | id |
| --- | --- |
|  | 1 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 3 |

| Request_Field table | id | request_id | field_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 1 | 1 | John |
|  | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2021-01-01 |
|  | 3 | 2 | 1 | Jane |
|  | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
|  | 5 | 3 | 1 | Jack |
|  | 6 | 3 | 2 | 2022-01-01 |

| Field table | id | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | name |
|  | 2 | desired_date |

The SQL query I try to make : get all *Request* ordered by the *desired_date* record of the Field table (DESC).

| Request desired results | id |
| --- | --- |
|  | 3 |
|  | 1 |
|  | 2 |

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done.

Comment: `EAV` is a problematic schema design.  Your 3-table version is even worse.  Redesign the schema.